# "print file.read()" Invalid Syntax in Python 3

Tags: python

I wanted to create a 10 files where each file has a *"blob"* word at the first sentence and read those sentence directly.
Here's my code:

```
import random
import string

for i in range(9):
    name = input('fileNumber')+ str(i+1) + '.txt'
    try:
        file = open(name,'w+')
        file = open(name,'a')
        file.write("blob")
        file = open(name,'r')
        print file.read()       #'file' being highlighted with red color when I execute
        file.close()
```

When I run it, I got an error message saying `Invalid syntax` and it highlights my `file.read()` line.

Can somebody tell me where's the flaw in my code?

EDIT: I'm currently using python 3.5. However, I could also switch to 2.7 as well!

Comment: What version of python are you using? Since python3, print has become a function instead of a statement.

Comment: @Ikke 3.5. Is it different tho?

Comment: @clcto so is it mean that I have to close first and then open again?

Answer (score 5):

Try doing this:

```
print(file.read())
```

In Python 3.x `print()` is a function and the parentheses are mandatory.

Comment: Downovter: care to comment?